# interpreting Gamma regression coefficients - individuals not totalling sum of parts

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution

I have fit a gamma regression to a dataset, and like with traditional linear regression, I would like to calculate the contribution of each independent variable across the entire model. The problem I have is, when I calculate each variable contribution separately and add those up, this does NOT equal the predicted value exactly (it's about 5% off). Reading up on this, it may not be possible given the log-link like distribution. But I am asking the experts.

Here's my example, this is a table of variables in my model with gamma coefficients, a selected observation and its values, and the math of coeff*obs value:

[image]

So for example, the model intercept value is 15.77.  The coefficient value of VAR1 is -0.000000004130.  The sample observation I am scoring has a VAR1 value equal to 8622138, a VAR2 value of 170 and so on.  If I multiply the model coefficient and the observation value, I get column D.  Add up Column D and I get the 0.3469 you see there.

To get the total predicted estimate of my sample site, you add the intercept value to the sum of the coeff*obs numbers and exponentiate that, like this:

EXP(15.77 + 0.3469)

That equals 10007063. This is the same value I get from my computer program, and so I can prove the approach works manually.

Here's the problem ... I want to know what each variable contribution value is, that is...I want to know how much VAR1 contributes to the 10007063 estimate. I want to calculate each VAR value and then show how each of those add up to the final estimate.  I have tried to exponentiate each VAR value, add them up and I only get close'ish.  Like this:

[image]

So here, I calculate the "coefficient contribution" column by exponentiating the VAR coefficient and Intercept and then backing out the intercept to have only the VAR amount remain. I then create column 2 here by simply multiplying the sample obs value to that, add up the sum, and I get close with the 9528878 value.  That's slightly off of my 10007063 estimate.

Is there a way in Gamma reg to get the sum of the parts to equal the overall total estimate?

Comment: The error you make is that exponentiating and then adding up is *always* different from exponentiating the sum (according to Jensen's Inequality).  However, there is no clear meaning of "amount of contribution" in this setting because that must depend on how much each of the variables might be able to change (or is varying in the dataset).